# Facing issues in publishing MAX30102 sensor data via a MQTT Broker to Influx DB for visualization of Sensor's data in Grafana

Tags: esp8266

I actually wanted to visualise MAX30102 sensor's data in Grafana.
So I used Raspberry Pi as an IoT server. I referred this video for my project : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DO2wHI6JWQ

But when the above video is for Barometric sensor to predict pressure, humidity and temperature.
I want to try it with MAX30102 Pulse Oximeter Sensor.

Here is my below code.
I want to convert the sensor's reading into Json File and publish it to NodeRed via MQTT.
The values are then inserted into InfluxDB.
Then I will use Influx DB values to visualise it in Grafana.

I am using ESP8266 connected with MAX30102 for measuring BPM. And for IoT server I am using Rasp Pi 4B.

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.hpp>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30105.h"
#include "heartRate.h"


MAX30105 particleSensor;

char* ssid = "Surya Home";
const char* password = "password";
const char* mqtt_server = "1.1.1.1"; //redacted for privacy reasons

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
unsigned long lastMsg = 0;
#define MSG_BUFFER_SIZE (50)
char msg[MSG_BUFFER_SIZE];
int value = 0;
const byte RATE_SIZE = 4; //Increase this for more averaging. 4 is good.
byte rates[RATE_SIZE]; //Array of heart rates
byte rateSpot = 0;
long lastBeat = 0; //Time at which the last beat occurred

float beatsPerMinute;
int beatAvg;
void setup_wifi() {

  delay(100);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  randomSeed(micros());

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {

}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Create a random client ID
    String clientId = "ESP8266Client-";
    clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str())) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      client.publish("outTopic", "hello world");
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe("inTopic");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Initializing...");

  // Initialize sensor
  if (!particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST)) //Use default I2C port, 400kHz speed
  {
    Serial.println("MAX30105 was not found. Please check wiring/power. ");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Place your index finger on the sensor with steady pressure.");

  particleSensor.setup(); //Configure sensor with default settings
  particleSensor.setPulseAmplitudeRed(0x0A); //Turn Red LED to low to indicate sensor is running
  particleSensor.setPulseAmplitudeGreen(0); //Turn off Green LED

  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
}

void loop() {

  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();
  StaticJsonDocument<32> doc;
  char output[55];

  long irValue = particleSensor.getIR();

  if (checkForBeat(irValue) == true)
  {
    //We sensed a beat!
    long delta = millis() - lastBeat;
    lastBeat = millis();

    beatsPerMinute = 60 / (delta / 1000.0);

    if (beatsPerMinute < 255 && beatsPerMinute > 20)
    {
      rates[rateSpot++] = (byte)beatsPerMinute; //Store this reading in the array
      rateSpot %= RATE_SIZE; //Wrap variable

      //Take average of readings
      beatAvg = 0;
      for (byte x = 0 ; x < RATE_SIZE ; x++)
        beatAvg += rates[x];
      beatAvg /= RATE_SIZE;
    }
  }
    doc["p"] = beatAvg;
    Serial.println("Read");

    serializeJson(doc, output);
    Serial.println(output);
    client.publish("/home/sensors", output);
    Serial.println("Sent");
}
```

However this is not working.

[image: Serial Monitor Error]

First I checked only with Heart rate measuring code.
It worked and I got values in serial monitor.

Second
I checked the example of connecting ESP8266 with wifi.
This one too worked.

But when I mixed both the code its not working both wifi and heartbeat functions not working.

What should I change to make it work ?
Or
Is there anyother ways I can visualise this data via Grafana ?